# Trigger redux form submit in componentWillReceiveProps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

When a user submits a form, I'm checking to see if a certain field's value has changed. If it has, I'm displaying a confirmation modal. If the user clicks "Yes" in the modal, the modal component sets the  "dismissedSubTypeChangeWarning" prop to true in redux.

Inside componentWillReceiveProps I listen for any changes to this prop. If it's value is true, I want to trigger the form's submission. I followed instructions at https://redux-form.com/6.5.0/examples/remotesubmit/ to configure this.

The dispatch call never fires, because in the console I see "detected dismiss" then nothing else. I expect to see "submitForm method" after "detected dismiss".

I condensed the code (below) to the most basic version to show the issue. When I run my code I see no errors in the console.

I found a solution using refs (see commented line), but faking a click  doesn't seem like a good practice.

```
class ChangeEditForm extends React.Component {
    componentWillReceiveProps (nextProps) {
        if (nextProps.dismissedSubTypeChangeWarning) {
        console.log('detected dismiss')
        this.props.toggleDismissedSubTypeChangeWarning()
        this.props.dispatch(submit('changeEdit'))
        // this.refs.submit.click()
        }
    }

    render () {
        <form onSubmit={this.props.handleSubmit(this.props.submitForm)}>
            <button type='submit' ref='submit'>Save</button>
        </form>
    }
}

const handlers = {
    submitForm: props => (formValues) => {
        console.log('submitForm method')
        if ((formValues.subtype !== props.initialValues.subtype) && !props.dismissedSubTypeChangeWarning) {
            console.log('show warning')
            props.toggleSubTypeChangeConfirmModal()
        } else {
            console.log('submitting form')
        }
    }
}

export function mapStateToProps (state, props) {
    return {
        dismissedSubTypeChangeWarning: state.ui.dismissedSubTypeChangeWarning
    }
}

export default compose(
    pure,
    reduxForm({
        form: 'changeEdit',
        onSubmit: handlers.submitForm
    }),
    connect(mapStateToProps, null),
    withRouter,
    withHandlers(handlers)
)(ChangeEditForm)
```

Answer (score 1):

I still think you're over complicating your form submission.

As mentioned in the comments, the form submits once, the values are checked once, a popup spawns if values are different, confirming in the popup updates values, otherwise canceling closes modal and leaves form as is.

By creating a `HOC` we can control the modal and the form without having to resubmit the form on popup confirmation.

Working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/lxv9o1nxzl

**container/ChangeNameHOC.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { reset } from "redux-form";
import { updateUser } from "../actions";
import { Values } from "redux-form-website-template";
import ChangeNameForm from "./ChangeNameForm";
import ShowModal from "../components/ShowModal";
import CurrentStore from "../containers/CurrentStore";

class ChangeNameHOC extends Component {
  state = {
    modalIsOpen: false,
    formProps: {}
  };

  openModal = () => this.setState({ modalIsOpen: true });

  closeModal = () => this.setState({ modalIsOpen: false });

  validateFormValues = formProps => {
    const { firstName, lastName } = this.props;
    const nextFirstName = formProps.firstName;
    const nextLastName = formProps.lastName;

    if (firstName !== nextFirstName || lastName !== nextLastName) {
      this.setState({ modalIsOpen: true, formProps });
    }
  };

  handleSubmit = () => {
    this.setState({ modalIsOpen: false }, () => {
      this.props.updateUser(this.state.formProps);
      this.props.reset("ChangeNameForm");
    });
  };

  render = () => (
    <div style={{ padding: "0px 20px" }}>
      <ShowModal
        {...this.state}
        {...this.props}
        afterOpenModal={this.afterOpenModal}
        openModal={this.openModal}
        closeModal={this.closeModal}
        handleSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
      />
      <ChangeNameForm validateFormValues={this.validateFormValues} />
      <CurrentStore />
      <Values form="ChangeNameForm" />
    </div>
  );
}

export default connect(
  state => ({
    firstName: state.user.firstName,
    lastName: state.user.lastName
  }),
  { updateUser, reset }
)(ChangeNameHOC);
```

**containers/ChangeNameForm.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { Field, reduxForm } from "redux-form";
import RenderField from "../components/RenderField";

const isRequired = value => (!value ? "Required" : undefined);

const ChangeNameForm = ({
  handleSubmit,
  reset,
  submitting,
  validateFormValues
}) => (
  <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(validateFormValues)}>
    <Field
      className="uk-input"
      label="First Name"
      name="firstName"
      component={RenderField}
      type="text"
      placeholder="First Name"
      validate={[isRequired]}
    />
    <Field
      className="uk-input"
      label="Last Name"
      name="lastName"
      component={RenderField}
      type="text"
      placeholder="Last Name"
      validate={[isRequired]}
    />
    <button
      className="uk-button uk-button-primary"
      type="submit"
      disabled={submitting}
      style={{ marginBottom: 20 }}
    >
      Submit
    </button>
    <div style={{ float: "right" }}>
      <button
        className="uk-button uk-button-danger"
        type="button"
        disabled={submitting}
        onClick={reset}
        style={{ marginBottom: 20 }}
      >
        Reset
      </button>
    </div>
  </form>
);

export default reduxForm({
  form: "ChangeNameForm"
})(ChangeNameForm);
```

**components/ShowModal.js**

```
import React, { PureComponent } from "react";
import Modal from "react-modal";

const customStyles = {
  content: {
    minWidth: "400px",
    top: "50%",
    left: "50%",
    right: "auto",
    bottom: "auto",
    marginRight: "-50%",
    transform: "translate(-50%, -50%)"
  }
};

Modal.setAppElement("#root");

export default class ShowModal extends PureComponent {
  showChange = (name, prevName, nextName) => (
    <div>
      {name}: <strong>{prevName}</strong> to <strong>{nextName}</strong>
    </div>
  );

  render = () => {
    const { firstName, lastName } = this.props;
    const { firstName: nextFirstName } = this.props.formProps;
    const { lastName: nextLastName } = this.props.formProps;

    return (
      <div>
        <Modal
          isOpen={this.props.modalIsOpen}
          onAfterOpen={this.props.afterOpenModal}
          onRequestClose={this.props.closeModal}
          style={customStyles}
          contentLabel="Are you sure?"
        >
          <h3>Are you sure you want to update?</h3>
          <div style={{ marginBottom: 20 }}>
            {firstName !== nextFirstName
              ? this.showChange("FirstName", firstName, nextFirstName)
              : null}
            {lastName !== nextLastName
              ? this.showChange("LastName", lastName, nextLastName)
              : null}
          </div>
          <button
            style={{ float: "left" }}
            className="uk-button uk-button-primary"
            onClick={this.props.handleSubmit}
          >
            confirm
          </button>
          <button
            style={{ float: "right" }}
            className="uk-button uk-button-danger"
            onClick={this.props.closeModal}
          >
            cancel
          </button>
        </Modal>
      </div>
    );
  };
}
```

Comment: If I place the submitForm method inside the class, it doesn't receive the updated value of prop.dismissedSubTypeChangeWarning. Placing event handlers within a  handlers object is a best practice, so I don't think that I'm over complicating things.

Comment: What you're asking for then doesn't make sense: 1.) User submits the form. 2.) Values are checked to see if a particular value changed, if so, displays a modal. 3.) If modal is confirmed, it then resubmits the same exact form again. But... why? Instead it should be: form submits once, values are checked once, if confirmed then allow form to send formProps to API and/or update Redux state; otherwise, if canceled, do nothing. Submitting the same form twice is unnecessary (as well as using `toggleSubTypeChangeConfirmModal`). I've updated the answer to include how to do it.

Comment: If this form in question is separate than the form being submitted, then the form in question must always be mounted and check for prop updates in its `componentDidUpdate` class method. Otherwise, if it's not mounted, then the form can't be submitted.

Comment: I up voted this since it could work for some people. In my project it won't work without a lot of refactoring. I'm using React portals for all modals, therefore since the modal isn't a child of the form I can't pass handleSubmit to the modal.

Comment: The portal shouldn't be a child of the form, but instead positioned alongside the form in a parent container -- they share a common parent, but each is its own separate component. Otherwise, your modal isn't going to be reusable and modular (you'll have to create 10 similar modals for 10 different forms). As a result, your form and modal will be always be disjointed and asynchronous, even though you're trying to join them in a synchronous way. Ideally, there should be one reusable modal that can be placed anywhere within your application.